# Unable to start Kernel due to connexion timeout - Jupyter and Python in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, python-venv

## Problem

I am currently having issues with the virtual environment I use to run Python code within a Jupyter notebook. After letting the project unopened for a week, I now cannot run anything. VS Code attempts to activate the venv then indicates that it cannot reach the kernel :

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
Unable to start Kernel '.venv2 (Python 3.10.6)' due to connection timeout. 
View Jupyter log for further details.
```

The adequate environment is selected in VSCode.
I have attached the Jupyter log below if necessary.

## Environment

- VS Code 1.72.0
- Mac
- Jupyter Extension Version: 2022.9.1002791758.
- Python Extension Version: 2022.16.0.
- Python 3.10.6
- Virtual environment `Venv`.

## Attempts to solve it

This has already happened once, and I was able to resolve this by creating a new venv altogether. However, I would like to find a definitive solution.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled all of jupyter packages. I have also updated all of my pip packages. I have checked that ipykernel is all there, which it is - version 6.16.0. As many people before, I have attempted the following in an external terminal with VS Code closed :

```
python -m pip install 'traitlets==4.3.3' --force-reinstall
```

This did not work. Other than creating dependency conflicts, it had no effect on the issue as Jupyter was still unable to start the kernel. I have also try to revert Tornado to 5.1.1, as it seems that it was part of this issue in some cases, and it did not change anything either.

#### Edit nº1

Following MingJie-MSFT's comment, I looked into the setting of the ipykernel package. I am running several venv in different folders and the documentation for the package indicates that "if you want to have multiple IPython kernels for different virtualenvs or conda environments, you will need to specify unique names for the kernelspecs". I had not done that, so I used `--display-name` to add the display name `"Python (.venv2)"` for the `.venv2` virtual environment.

This definitely seems to have solved the problem in many cases, as there is no more problems with the kernel. I used this command :

```
source .venv2/bin/activate
python -m ipykernel install --user --name .venv2 --display-name "Python (.venv2)"
```

There are two effects that I still need to look into. First, my cells take significantly longer to run. Second, some of them do not work at all, apparently those which rely on Plotly. I think this has to do with my Python code itself, my pip packages, and the fact that my folder is on a cloud and there may be synchronisation issues. That's another problem so I will address it elsewhere.

### Pip Packages

```
Package              Version
-------------------- -----------
appnope              0.1.3
argon2-cffi          21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings 21.2.0
asttokens            2.0.8
attrs                22.1.0
backcall             0.2.0
beautifulsoup4       4.11.1
bleach               5.0.1
cffi                 1.15.1
contourpy            1.0.5
cycler               0.11.0
DateTime             4.7
debugpy              1.6.3
decorator            5.1.1
defusedxml           0.7.1
entrypoints          0.4
et-xmlfile           1.1.0
executing            1.1.0
fastjsonschema       2.16.2
fonttools            4.37.4
ipykernel            6.16.0
ipython              8.5.0
ipython-genutils     0.2.0
ipywidgets           8.0.2
jedi                 0.18.1
Jinja2               3.1.2
jsonschema           4.16.0
jupyter              1.0.0
jupyter_client       7.3.5
jupyter-console      6.4.4
jupyter-core         4.11.1
jupyterlab-pygments  0.2.2
jupyterlab-widgets   3.0.3
kiwisolver           1.4.4
lxml                 4.9.1
MarkupSafe           2.1.1
matplotlib           3.6.0
matplotlib-inline    0.1.6
mistune              2.0.4
nbclient             0.7.0
nbconvert            7.2.1
nbformat             5.6.1
nest-asyncio         1.5.6
notebook             6.4.12
numpy                1.23.3
openpyxl             3.0.10
packaging            21.3
pandas               1.5.0
pandocfilters        1.5.0
parso                0.8.3
pexpect              4.8.0
pickleshare          0.7.5
Pillow               9.2.0
pip                  22.2.2
pip-review           1.2.0
plotly               5.10.0
prometheus-client    0.14.1
prompt-toolkit       3.0.31
psutil               5.9.2
ptyprocess           0.7.0
pure-eval            0.2.2
pycparser            2.21
Pygments             2.13.0
pyparsing            3.0.9
pyrsistent           0.18.1
python-dateutil      2.8.2
pytz                 2022.4
pyzmq                24.0.1
qtconsole            5.3.2
QtPy                 2.2.1
Send2Trash           1.8.0
setuptools           65.4.1
six                  1.16.0
soupsieve            2.3.2.post1
stack-data           0.5.1
tenacity             8.1.0
terminado            0.16.0
tinycss2             1.1.1
tornado              6.2
traitlets            5.4.0
wcwidth              0.2.5
webencodings         0.5.1
wheel                0.37.1
widgetsnbextension   4.0.3
zope.interface       5.4.0
```

### Jupyter Log

```
Visual Studio Code (1.72.0, undefined, desktop)
Jupyter Extension Version: 2022.9.1002791758.
Python Extension Version: 2022.16.0.
Workspace folder /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD
info 13:31:50.908: ZMQ install verified.
User belongs to experiment group 'jupyterTest'
User belongs to experiment group 'jupyterEnhancedDataViewer'
info 13:31:51.260: LSP Notebooks experiment is enabled
info 13:31:52.245: Starting Jupyter Session startUsingPythonInterpreter, .jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python.-m#ipykernel_launcher (Python Path: /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2, EnvType: Venv, EnvName: '.venv2', Version: 3.10.6) for '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/UK/SummaryUK.ipynb' (disableUI=true)
info 13:31:52.245: Computing working directory for resource '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/UK/SummaryUK.ipynb'
info 13:31:52.268: Preferred Remote kernel for /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/UK/SummaryUK.ipynb is undefined
info 13:31:53.343: Preferred Remote kernel for /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/UK/SummaryUK.ipynb is undefined
info 13:31:53.344: Find preferred kernel for /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/UK/SummaryUK.ipynb with metadata {"kernelspec":{"display_name":"Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)","language":"python","name":"python3"},"language_info":{"name":"python","version":"3.10.6"},"orig_nbformat":4,"vscode":{"interpreter":{"hash":"73b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842"}}} & preferred interpreter 
info 13:31:53.345: Preferred Remote kernel for /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/UK/SummaryUK.ipynb is undefined
info 13:31:53.345: Preferred kernel .jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python.-m#ipykernel_launcher is exact match or top match for non python kernels, (false, undefined, true, false)
info 13:31:53.346: PreferredConnection: .jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python.-m#ipykernel_launcher found for NotebookDocument: /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/UK/SummaryUK.ipynb
info 13:31:53.372: Got env vars ourselves faster /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python with env var count 30 in 1128ms
info 13:31:53.372: Got env vars ourselves faster /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python with env var count 30 in 1121ms
info 13:31:53.372: Got env vars ourselves faster /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python with env var count 30 in 1087ms
info 13:31:53.372: Got env vars ourselves faster /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python with env var count 30 in 1087ms
info 13:31:53.375: Process Execution: > ~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python -m pip list
> ~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python -m pip list
info 13:31:53.380: Process Execution: > ~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python -c "import ipykernel; print(ipykernel.__version__); print("5dc3a68c-e34e-4080-9c3e-2a532b2ccb4d"); print(ipykernel.__file__)"
> ~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python -c "import ipykernel; print(ipykernel.__version__); print("5dc3a68c-e34e-4080-9c3e-2a532b2ccb4d"); print(ipykernel.__file__)"
info 13:31:53.383: Process Execution: > ~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python -m ipykernel_launcher --ip=127.0.0.1 --stdin=9008 --control=9006 --hb=9005 --Session.signature_scheme="hmac-sha256" --Session.key=b"349ea1b4-8ed3-4337-a198-27f9199872da" --shell=9007 --transport="tcp" --iopub=9009 --f=/Users/theoleschevin/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-v2-455694J8M86a7sjjx.json
> ~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python -m ipykernel_launcher --ip=127.0.0.1 --stdin=9008 --control=9006 --hb=9005 --Session.signature_scheme="hmac-sha256" --Session.key=b"349ea1b4-8ed3-4337-a198-27f9199872da" --shell=9007 --transport="tcp" --iopub=9009 --f=/Users/theoleschevin/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-v2-455694J8M86a7sjjx.json
info 13:31:53.383: Process Execution: cwd: ~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/UK
cwd: ~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/UK
info 13:31:54.224: ipykernel version & path 6.16.0, ~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py for /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python
info 13:31:54.580: Got env vars with python /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python, with env var count 30 and custom env var count 0 in 2295ms
info 13:31:54.581: Got env vars with python /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python, with env var count 30 and custom env var count 0 in 2330ms
info 13:31:54.582: Got env vars with python /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python, with env var count 30 and custom env var count 0 in 2337ms
info 13:31:54.598: Got env vars with python /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python, with env var count 30 and custom env var count 0 in 2313ms
error 13:32:53.388: waitUntilUsed timed out [Error: timeout
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/Users/theoleschevin/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1002791758/out/extension.node.js:2:1295264)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)]
error 13:32:53.389: Disposing kernel process due to an error [a [Error]: Unable to start Kernel '.venv2 (Python 3.10.6)' due to connection timeout. 
View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    at /Users/theoleschevin/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1002791758/out/extension.node.js:2:2193691
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    at async x.launch (/Users/theoleschevin/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1002791758/out/extension.node.js:2:2193762)] {
  category: 'timeout',
  kernelConnectionMetadata: {
    kind: 'startUsingPythonInterpreter',
    kernelSpec: {
      specFile: '/Users/theoleschevin/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1002791758/temp/jupyter/kernels/python3106jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842/kernel.json',
      interpreterPath: '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python',
      isRegisteredByVSC: 'registeredByNewVersionOfExt',
      name: 'python3106jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842',
      argv: [Array],
      language: 'python',
      executable: 'python',
      display_name: "Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)",
      metadata: [Object],
      env: {}
    },
    interpreter: {
      id: '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python',
      sysPrefix: '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2',
      envType: 'Venv',
      envName: '.venv2',
      envPath: [p],
      architecture: 3,
      sysVersion: '3.10.6 (v3.10.6:9c7b4bd164, Aug  1 2022, 17:13:48) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]',
      version: [Object],
      displayName: "Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)",
      detailedDisplayName: "Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)",
      uri: [p]
    },
    id: '.jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python.-m#ipykernel_launcher'
  }
}
error 13:32:53.389: 
info 13:32:53.389: Dispose Kernel process 45633.
error 13:32:53.432: Kernel Launcher. launch, Class name = r, completed in 61181ms, has a falsy return value, Arg 1: {"kind":"startUsingPythonInterpreter","kernelSpec":{"specFile":"/Users/theoleschevin/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1002791758/temp/jupyter/kernels/python3106jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842/kernel.json","interpreterPath":"/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python","isRegisteredByVSC":"registeredByNewVersionOfExt","name":"python3106jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842","argv":["python","-m","ipykernel_launcher","-f","{connection_file}"],"language":"python","executable":"python","display_name":"Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)","metadata":{"interpreter":{"path":"/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python"}},"env":{}},"interpreter":{"id":"/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python","sysPrefix":"/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2","envType":"Venv","envName":".venv2","envPath":{"$mid":1,"fsPath":"/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2","path":"/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2","scheme":"file"},"architecture":3,"sysVersion":"3.10.6 (v3.10.6:9c7b4bd164, Aug  1 2022, 17:13:48) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]","version":{"raw":"3.10.6","major":3,"minor":10,"patch":6,"build":[],"prerelease":["final","0"]},"displayName":"Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)","detailedDisplayName":"Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)","uri":{"$mid":1,"fsPath":"/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python","external":"file:///Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles%20et%20Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python","path":"/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python","scheme":"file"}},"id":".jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python.-m#ipykernel_launcher"}, Arg 2: 60000, Arg 3: "~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/UK/SummaryUK.ipynb", Arg 4: "~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/UK", Arg 5: <argument cannot be serialized for logging> [a [Error]: Unable to start Kernel '.venv2 (Python 3.10.6)' due to connection timeout. 
View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    at /Users/theoleschevin/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1002791758/out/extension.node.js:2:2193691
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    at async x.launch (/Users/theoleschevin/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1002791758/out/extension.node.js:2:2193762)] {
  category: 'timeout',
  kernelConnectionMetadata: {
    kind: 'startUsingPythonInterpreter',
    kernelSpec: {
      specFile: '/Users/theoleschevin/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1002791758/temp/jupyter/kernels/python3106jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842/kernel.json',
      interpreterPath: '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python',
      isRegisteredByVSC: 'registeredByNewVersionOfExt',
      name: 'python3106jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842',
      argv: [Array],
      language: 'python',
      executable: 'python',
      display_name: "Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)",
      metadata: [Object],
      env: {}
    },
    interpreter: {
      id: '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python',
      sysPrefix: '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2',
      envType: 'Venv',
      envName: '.venv2',
      envPath: [p],
      architecture: 3,
      sysVersion: '3.10.6 (v3.10.6:9c7b4bd164, Aug  1 2022, 17:13:48) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]',
      version: [Object],
      displayName: "Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)",
      detailedDisplayName: "Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)",
      uri: [p]
    },
    id: '.jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python.-m#ipykernel_launcher'
  }
}
error 13:32:53.433: Failed to connect raw kernel session: Error: Unable to start Kernel '.venv2 (Python 3.10.6)' due to connection timeout. 
View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
warn 13:32:53.437: Error occurred while trying to start the kernel, options.disableUI=false [a [Error]: Unable to start Kernel '.venv2 (Python 3.10.6)' due to connection timeout. 
View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    at /Users/theoleschevin/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1002791758/out/extension.node.js:2:2193691
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    at async x.launch (/Users/theoleschevin/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1002791758/out/extension.node.js:2:2193762)] {
  category: 'timeout',
  kernelConnectionMetadata: {
    kind: 'startUsingPythonInterpreter',
    kernelSpec: {
      specFile: '/Users/theoleschevin/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1002791758/temp/jupyter/kernels/python3106jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842/kernel.json',
      interpreterPath: '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python',
      isRegisteredByVSC: 'registeredByNewVersionOfExt',
      name: 'python3106jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842',
      argv: [Array],
      language: 'python',
      executable: 'python',
      display_name: "Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)",
      metadata: [Object],
      env: {}
    },
    interpreter: {
      id: '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python',
      sysPrefix: '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2',
      envType: 'Venv',
      envName: '.venv2',
      envPath: [p],
      architecture: 3,
      sysVersion: '3.10.6 (v3.10.6:9c7b4bd164, Aug  1 2022, 17:13:48) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]',
      version: [Object],
      displayName: "Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)",
      detailedDisplayName: "Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)",
      uri: [p]
    },
    id: '.jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python.-m#ipykernel_launcher'
  }
}
warn 13:32:53.438: Kernel Error, context = start [a [Error]: Unable to start Kernel '.venv2 (Python 3.10.6)' due to connection timeout. 
View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    at /Users/theoleschevin/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1002791758/out/extension.node.js:2:2193691
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    at async x.launch (/Users/theoleschevin/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1002791758/out/extension.node.js:2:2193762)] {
  category: 'timeout',
  kernelConnectionMetadata: {
    kind: 'startUsingPythonInterpreter',
    kernelSpec: {
      specFile: '/Users/theoleschevin/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1002791758/temp/jupyter/kernels/python3106jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842/kernel.json',
      interpreterPath: '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python',
      isRegisteredByVSC: 'registeredByNewVersionOfExt',
      name: 'python3106jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842',
      argv: [Array],
      language: 'python',
      executable: 'python',
      display_name: "Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)",
      metadata: [Object],
      env: {}
    },
    interpreter: {
      id: '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python',
      sysPrefix: '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2',
      envType: 'Venv',
      envName: '.venv2',
      envPath: [p],
      architecture: 3,
      sysVersion: '3.10.6 (v3.10.6:9c7b4bd164, Aug  1 2022, 17:13:48) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]',
      version: [Object],
      displayName: "Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)",
      detailedDisplayName: "Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)",
      uri: [p]
    },
    id: '.jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python.-m#ipykernel_launcher'
  }
}
info 13:32:53.440: Got env vars with python /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python, with env var count 30 and custom env var count 0 in 2ms
info 13:32:53.440: Got env vars ourselves faster /Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python with env var count 30 in 2ms
info 13:32:53.444: Process Execution: > ~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python -c "import ipykernel"
> ~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python -c "import ipykernel"
info 13:32:53.837: Dispose Kernel '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/UK/SummaryUK.ipynb' associated with '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/UK/SummaryUK.ipynb'
error 13:32:53.839: Error in execution [a [Error]: Unable to start Kernel '.venv2 (Python 3.10.6)' due to connection timeout. 
View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    at /Users/theoleschevin/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1002791758/out/extension.node.js:2:2193691
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    at async x.launch (/Users/theoleschevin/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1002791758/out/extension.node.js:2:2193762)] {
  category: 'timeout',
  kernelConnectionMetadata: {
    kind: 'startUsingPythonInterpreter',
    kernelSpec: {
      specFile: '/Users/theoleschevin/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1002791758/temp/jupyter/kernels/python3106jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842/kernel.json',
      interpreterPath: '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python',
      isRegisteredByVSC: 'registeredByNewVersionOfExt',
      name: 'python3106jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842',
      argv: [Array],
      language: 'python',
      executable: 'python',
      display_name: "Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)",
      metadata: [Object],
      env: {}
    },
    interpreter: {
      id: '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/bin/python',
      sysPrefix: '/Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2',
      envType: 'Venv',
      envName: '.venv2',
      envPath: [p],
      architecture: 3,
      sysVersion: '3.10.6 (v3.10.6:9c7b4bd164, Aug  1 2022, 17:13:48) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]',
      version: [Object],
      displayName: "Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)",
      detailedDisplayName: "Python 3.10.6 ('.venv2': venv)",
      uri: [p]
    },
    id: '.jvsc74a57bd073b427e724cc124a6e83459597e858deb3a8732b6302a65cc8c3c54873670842./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python./Users/theoleschevin/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/Articles et Projet/EnnemisInterieur/BD/.venv2/python.-m#ipykernel_launcher'
  }
}
```

Comment: Can reinstall ipykernal help? use command `pip uninstall ipykernal` and `pip install ipykernal`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, unfortunately this had no effect. However I looked into `ipykernel` in more details and there seems to be an issue with the way I had set up the kernel. I edited my post to explain this.

Comment: I have a few questions which may help me judge. Do you use VPN? Has this problem occurred before? Is it effective to restart vscode or reinstall jupyter and python extensions?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error because I was using a system proxy. When I turned it off, `jupyter` worked fine.
So I think the problem is your laptop networking, not your packages.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue and temporarily disabled my firewall. In my situation, it appears that the problem was caused by my antivirus software. (I'm using ESET internet security) but as soon as I enable the firewall the problem comes back and I havn't been able to find a solution or a specific rule in firewall to fix it.